# Does All Services in the same process killed when OS kill one of them?

Tags: android, service, kill-process

Hi i have an android application contains 3 background services running together.
if android OS decides to kill it (one of them)! Dose all this service will be terminated or just one of them and the other keep working?
thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As OS philosophy says -

- if more then one services (lets call it thread for more clearer view ) is executing under one process .The process can govern over them .
- If u kill the process , all the services under it would be stopped or killed like in a war.
  but if you kill one service it might not happen that the process is killed.

Look for the better assumption and view suppose

- The war tank is a process and soldiers (which might have been working differently inside are services ).
- Now what will happen when the tank(The Process)  gets a blast by missile(assume it OS).All the insider will die. [ :) it was a serious hit]
- What will happen if somehow a bullet hits any of the inside soldier .
  hope  you can get the idea what happens when .

Comment: thanks man, that exactly what i need. but (for more clear) : is android OS on low memory kill the the hole process, or just the service they decide to kill.

Comment: Every process have its memory , it is assigned to it once when it is created by OS  (no matter which OS is this as per core Computer Science says).
all the threads under it will have to share this much allocation of  memory.
so that there might be no chance of memory fighting of the current process with other processes so they(threads) are best fit within what they got.

Answer (score 1):

This is nowhere documented and you should design your application such that every of your servie wouldn't cause crash or whatever if any other service(s) killed.
Having said that a service being killed by OS is most unlikely.